# Combine different formulas/functions within the same cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-2010, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make some sort of check box list for some features for a product, if some features apply depending on the buyer, the amount of $ should add to the cell and so on. If you put "yes" the amount of $ should add to the "total" cell and if you put "no" it should stay the same. Now, the thing is that the "total" cell is the one getting all the formulas so I need to combine them. If the quantity of products is greater, equal or less then the base 'total' amount changes, then if certain bonus features apply to this product then by typing 'yes' certain amount of $ also adds to the 'total' cell and so on.

I already used the IF, IFS, and AND formulas but nothing seems to work. when using IFS once the first condition checks true then it doesn't run through the rest.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to use is the good old + (plus sign). for example,

```
=D2 + IF(C2="Yes",E2,0) + IF(F2="Yes",120,0)
```

or, for the de-luxe version add 50%,

```
=(D2 + IF(C2="Yes",E2,0) + IF(F2="Yes",120,0)) * IF(H2="Yes",1.5, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, unknown benefactor, for marking my answer with a negative point. Care to elaborate your reasons?